# Performance of updating options in chosen select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-chosen, twitter-bootstrap-2

I use [jQuery Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) plugin for select boxes and Bootstrap 2.3.2. I have two select boxes with same options, where values are strings. If I select option in first select box, this option is disabled in second select box and vice versa. If I deselect option in first select box, this option is enabled in second select box and vice versa.

Basically, i have two selected boxes, which have the same options but you can select the same options only in one select box.

I use reset button for first select box, which update the select boxes to initial state. It means for all options in first select box `selected` attribute is false and for all options in second select box `disabled` attribute is false.

The problem is performance. When i click the reset button, updating of option attributes and chosen select box is too long. I want to use reset button for select boxes with more than one thousand options, but i don't know if i should change my code or use another select box plugin.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/he4pLsve/)

```
$(".keywordContain").click(function(){
    $('select[name=keywordContainSelect] option').prop('selected', false).trigger('chosen:updated');
    $('select[name=keywordNotContainSelect] option').prop('disabled', false).trigger('chosen:updated');
});
```

Comment: you can test js performance in http://jsperf.com, it's very good and usefull

Comment: @Luizgrs first it'd be necessary to isolate the code that's causing the slowdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is currently triggering the "chosen:updated" event for each option element. You only need to do it for the `<select>`:

```
$(".keywordContain").click(function () {
    $('select[name=keywordContainSelect] option').prop('selected', false);
    $('select[name=keywordNotContainSelect] option').prop('disabled', false);
    $(".selectKeyword").trigger("chosen:updated");
});
```

[Here is the updated jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/fzo74ve7/)

Comment: You are right, thank you. I didn't realize that mistake.